# Responsive absolutely positioned menu

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive-design, absolute

I hava a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/jxvg7zvd/30/

It's a really simple example of a nav with a large menu under the 5th link.

The large menu is absoutely positioned below the link and links inside it have percentage widths

I would like the large menu to be responsive so when the window is smaller the links inside the menu will be narrower.

Because the menu is absolutely positioned when the window is resized it won't resize.

How can I have a large hover menu like this that is responsive.

```
    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="top-nav">
            <li><a href="">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
            <li class="btn"><a href="">Five</a>
                <div class="mega-nav">
                    <div class="block">
                        <ul class="block-nav">
                            <li><a href="">One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block">
                        <ul class="block-nav">
                            <li><a href="">One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block">
                        <ul class="block-nav">
                            <li><a href="">One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block">
                        <ul class="block-nav">
                            <li><a href="">One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block">
                        <ul class="block-nav">
                            <li><a href="">One</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't using media queries work for this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Have you tried using a media query to change the width of .mega-nav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS media queries, like this:

```
@media (max-width:600px) {
    .mega-nav {
        width: 400px;
    }
}

@media (max-width:400px) {
    .mega-nav {
        width: 250px;
    }
}
```

You probably want to tweak those values and maybe add some more media queries though :)